# How to redirect a Drupal node after loading Google Analytics tracking code?

Tags: templates, redirect, drupal, google-analytics, header

I am working on a Drupal site where I need to track visits to some redirecting nodes. I need this because both the original link (outbound links from a mobile app) and the final destination are outside the site.

I know I can add redirect code to the header of specific nodes, but I need help on a couple things:
- how technically do I do this? I have created node.tpl.php templates for specific node types before... is this the way to go? and how should the redirect code be formatted? if I have more than one node for this type, I presume I will have to create single php files for them, like this
nodeid-type.tpl.php correct?
- where does the GA code go? the whole site is tracked through the Google Analytics module, so won't the code I add to these specific nodes create a conflict with this? Or do I just not add any GA code to the tpls and let the module track the visit to the page? Will that happen in the correct order so that the header redirection still allows for the page visit to be tracked?

thanks for any help, I'm not an IT but I am a quick learner and do have some coding experience with WP and Drupal, so give me a chance ;)

Elena

Comment: If you redirect in the header, the page will never be rendered, so the GA javascript will never be executed. You'll either have to send the data across manually through Google's API (before redirecting), or implement a javascript-based redirect that happens after the page has loaded

Comment: Thanks @Clive! Javascript-based redirection then... how do I do that? I found this page on drupal_goto() https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7 is this the right function to use? and how do I add it to specific nodes, using templates or in a different way?